# Can't display images from block content with PortableText

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

It been really long time I stuck with this issue. I'm still learning but can't move because of this partically case.

Links and texts are good but I couldn't show the images whatever I did, didn't work.

I'm working on standard project that I generated [here](https://www.sanity.io/create?template=sanity-io/sanity-template-nextjs-blog-comments)

```
import markdownStyles from "./markdown-styles.module.css";
import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";


export default function PostBody({ content }) {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto" className={markdownStyles.markdown}>
      <PortableText value={content} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the output I get from the content. I can see image type. I also tried by adding custom component, but still didn't work

```
    [
    {
    "_key": "5ce765e42eb5",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "c57bc9898e06",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [
            "836416fa85ed"
        ],
        "text": "Welcome to my new blog!"
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": [
        {
        "_key": "836416fa85ed",
        "_type": "link",
        "href": "https://google.com"
        }
    ],
    "style": "h2"
    },
    {
    "_key": "11b612a096de",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "bf13eac39637",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": "Sanity.io lets me work with structured content. That means I can add more content types. Who knows, I might add my portfolio, "
        },
        {
        "_key": "c9fe6a6bb0f3",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [
            "e202c343ba02"
        ],
        "text": "maybe a podcast"
        },
        {
        "_key": "7a203dce7337",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": ", "
        },
        {
        "_key": "94459dbc472b",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [
            "9fbf2c53c020"
        ],
        "text": "some products that I need to market"
        },
        {
        "_key": "e5d3752691f2",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": ", or my poetry collection (that I totally have)! I can even connect other frontends to my Sanity project when I find that new framework I just need to try out."
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": [
        {
        "_key": "e202c343ba02",
        "_type": "link",
        "href": "https://github.com/kmelve/sanity-plugin-podcast"
        },
        {
        "_key": "9fbf2c53c020",
        "_type": "link",
        "href": "https://www.sanity.io/blog/e-commerce-sample-schema"
        }
    ],
    "style": "normal"
    },
    {
    "_key": "5cdb13c0961f",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "a0d77a44e824",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": ""
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": [],
    "style": "normal"
    },
    {
    "_key": "23a029d1e942",
    "_type": "image",
    "asset": {
        "_ref": "image-a526b96131f4da2799071600492f8afbe4de62a3-900x900-webp",
        "_type": "reference"
    }
    },
    {
    "_key": "a8744e882bab",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "f028ef71c8e2",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": "img"
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": [],
    "style": "normal"
    },
    {
    "_key": "398aea7e852b",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "ce6249854da8",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": "But firstly, how could I make this blog my own special place on the internet?"
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": [],
    "style": "normal"
    },
    {
    "_key": "4e33a24403f6",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "0a678ac11d25",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": "I should probably check out the tutorial videos on how to get started with customizing both the content schema and the frontend accordingly."
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": []
    },
    {
    "_key": "13ba10479b9c",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "2c71eab6accc",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": "There's plenty of cool things I could explore:"
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": []
    },
    {
    "_key": "be751db6e0d0",
    "_type": "image",
    "asset": {
        "_ref": "image-c6f278aa0550e1c5617d26e67944086f8a21a4c8-800x800-webp",
        "_type": "reference"
    },
    "crop": {
        "_type": "sanity.imageCrop",
        "bottom": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "right": 0,
        "top": 0
    },
    "hotspot": {
        "_type": "sanity.imageHotspot",
        "height": 1,
        "width": 1,
        "x": 0.5,
        "y": 0.5
    }
    },
    {
    "_key": "557a095c0eed",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "43364982b47a",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [
            "27519f331ef1"
        ],
        "text": "How to customize content schemas"
        }
    ],
    "level": 1,
    "listItem": "bullet",
    "markDefs": [
        {
        "_key": "27519f331ef1",
        "_type": "link",
        "href": "https://www.sanity.io/docs/the-blog-template"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "_key": "698010eacb6f",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "2913625481f0",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [
            "e7e3f00bdddf"
        ],
        "text": "How to use structure builder to make my own workflows"
        }
    ],
    "level": 1,
    "listItem": "bullet",
    "markDefs": [
        {
        "_key": "e7e3f00bdddf",
        "_type": "link",
        "href": "https://www.sanity.io/docs/content-studio/structure-builder"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "_key": "36bf78dc4fad",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "81b76c937c46",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [
            "0a3a661f75ef"
        ],
        "text": "How to manage widgets on my dashboard"
        }
    ],
    "level": 1,
    "listItem": "bullet",
    "markDefs": [
        {
        "_key": "0a3a661f75ef",
        "_type": "link",
        "href": "https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/blob/next/packages/%40sanity/dashboard/README.md"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "_key": "5112fa59322d",
    "_type": "block",
    "children": [
        {
        "_key": "8901d5ceef26",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [
            "bd816d006b06"
        ],
        "text": "the friendly developer community"
        },
        {
        "_key": "ff01f7459236",
        "_type": "span",
        "marks": [],
        "text": "."
        }
    ],
    "markDefs": [
        {
        "_key": "bd816d006b06",
        "_type": "link"
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render the images coming from your portable text, you need to generate the URL for those images using some utilities provided by Sanity: [Sanity image url-builder](https://www.sanity.io/docs/image-url) and optionally [Sanity asset utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sanity/asset-utils) to get images dimensions, etc.

Once you configure these tools following docs instructions, you can customize how you render your content using the `components` prop of the `PortableText` component (basically styling the output however you want). Read more about this [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@portabletext/react).

When it comes to querying for images in Sanity documents, most of the time you don't really need the `url-builder` since you can directly query for the URL of the asset. However, it's different when you query for images that have been added in a rich text editor since Sanity doesn't provide a URL for the asset, you need to build it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ivanatias. Link you shared helped me a lot.